# Dereferencing VOID ** in a struct

Tags: c, struct, stack

So I'm trying to implement a stack using a struck and I'm in a pickle...

My .C File definitions:

```
typedef struct stack
 {
  unsigned int capacity;
  unsigned int size;
  unsigned int element_size;
  void **buffer;
}stack_t;

stack_t *Create(const unsigned int capacity, const unsigned int element_size)
{ 
  stack_t *ptr;
  ptr = (stack_t *)malloc(sizeof(stack_t));
  ptr->capacity = capacity;
  ptr->element_size = element_size;
  ptr->size = -1;
  ptr->buffer = malloc(sizeof(void *) * capacity);
  return ptr;
}
int Push(stack_t * stack, void * const ptr)
{ // void * const ptr - hold the char we want to pass into the stack
  assert(stack);
  if ((stack->size + 1) < stack->capacity)
  {
    stack->size++;
    *(stack->buffer + stack->size) = ptr;
    printf("Test: %c\n", *(char*)*(stack->buffer + stack->size));
    return (0);
  }

  else
  {
    printf("Stack Overflow\n");
  }
}
```

My issue is that I don't know which type of variable the user will input, for my testing I've per-made an array of chars to see if it works and array of int and it works perfectly.

If I try to de-reference my VOID **buffer in a given location and print the value using this format it works:

```
 *(type-cast)*(buffer->stack + buffer->size)
```

What if the type definition isn't specified?
And is presumably entered by the user, I've also allocated an element_size member in my struck so the user can input the amount of BYTES each element holds, but can't seem to figure out how to really de-reference without knowing the (type-cast) beforehand.

If you need me to post the entire code let me know.

Comment: You need to store the type information in your `stack_t`. Otherwise, just trust the user of `stack_t` to know which type he/she put in the stack. The user will know how to dereference by just casting to the original type.

Comment: Your approach is wrong, what you have is just pointers to elements. What you want to have is store the elements itself in the data structure. You need to figure out how to use the element size and memcpy the elements in the data structure. You don't need to know the type, all you need to know is how many bytes to copy in and out.

Comment: Thank you both on your answers,
@TedLyngmo - yes you are correct on this one, after referring to some outsource help, my friend also confirmed me with what you said, I don't really care the about the type-cast because the this is only a infrastructure (something I wasn't aware of) and if the user want to de-refrence it he can do it by himself.

Comment: @малинчекуров - Thank you also on this comment, what you suggest is adding to my Struct stack another member? but how can I store the elements in my data structure without knowing the cast type? I mean, how would I initiate something without knowing which type on initiation I'm about to do, say the user wants to send 1 stack for int and than another for chars, how can the struct (each one) hold its own type? any suggestions or references I can read about?

Comment: You don't need the type. You have the address and the size. Just memcpy the data. And learn about size_t.

Comment: @DavidEden you need to change the way you look at it - forget about all the types and only think of sizes. Your purpose is data structure which can store different size stuff(not different type, but different size, forget types). You already have the size member. So what do you need to do? When someone wants to push something inside, you copy that thing with its size inside. When someone wants to pop something out, you copy that thing with its size outside. That's it.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow - I'll read more about memcpy and size_t.
Thank you.

Comment: @малинчекуров - Yeah I figured I wasn't looking on this subject from the correct perspective I'll have to make my research about it.